# SceneKit drops to 30FPS when not moving

Tags: ios, scenekit, core-motion

I have an scene with a few nodes. When there is some animation then it works with 60FPS. But when objects are not moving, it's dropping to 30FPS. I'm rotating camera using coremotion, so this is visible. Is there anything I can do to stop this behavior and keep 60FPS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to force a continuous refresh of the SCNView:

```
view.playing=YES
view.loops=YES
```

Comment: @Toyos can you add the camera to the filter that stops this reduction in framerate? So if the camera is moving, this framerate stepdown doesn't happen?